# Visual Studio 2015 Command Window Suggestions Text Cut Off

Tags: visual-studio-2015, command-window

To find files in my solution, I rely heavily on the command window - I type "of" (for 'open file'), then the name of the file, and choose the one I want from the selections that pop up. However, on my new PC, the window that pops up with the options is cut off / too narrow, so that it does not show the part to the right of the portion of the name that I've typed (the width of the window expands as I type to extend just to the right of the last character I've typed). Is there any way to fix this so that I can see the locations of the files it's showing me, which are there to the right but hidden due to this UI issue?

Many thanks for any assistance!

[image: command window autosuggestions list]

Comment: Can you drag the bottom right corner!?

Comment: Oh! Yes, I hadn't noticed that little drag spot! Thank you! If you post as an answer instead of a comment I'll mark your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drag the bottom right corner and Visual Studio will remember your setting for next time.